# Terraform set variable with condition

Tags: terraform, terraform0.11

I'm trying to set a variable to a string that will later be joined with another string for an aws s3 bucket policy. I'm trying to do this by defining a local variable, but I also need to specify a condition in which I would want to use this. I am using terraform 11.

for instance:

- if set_bucket_policy is false then make the variable an empty string ""
- otherwise use a heredoc to set the string value of the variable

example, not working code:

```
locals {
  my_bucket_policy = var.set_bucket_policy == "false" ? "" : <<EOF
  {
    "Action": "s3:Get*",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/myrole"
    },
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
      "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
    ],
    "Sid": ""
  }
  EOF
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: Error: Error loading modules: module mymodule: Error parsing .terraform/modules/56fe672fc5a95438bdd61eddf28b668b/s3.tf: At 12:29: Unknown token: 12:29 IDENT var.set_bucket_policy

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty close, I created a small sample showing how to use conditionals. For more details, you can check out Terraform's [Conditional Expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

**main.tf**

```
variable "set_bucket_policy" {
    type = bool
}

output "my_bucket_policy" {
    value = var.set_bucket_policy == false ? "is set to false" : "is set to true"
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
% terraform apply -var 'set_bucket_policy=false' -auto-approve

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

my_bucket_policy = is set to false
% terraform apply -var 'set_bucket_policy=true' -auto-approve

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

my_bucket_policy = is set to true
```

Answer (score 0):

there are ways to do it and everyone do it in there own way i did it in this way.

i will check directly bucket policy variable like

```
bucket_policy_variable = var.bucket_policy == false : "" ? var.bucketpolicy_json
```

I did this in my ec2 module to set subnet dynamically i did set one variable setting up network scope

```
  variable "subnet_boundary" {
  description = "Variable to declare instance network boundary it could be public or private"
  default = "public"
}
```

Then in my ec2 code snippet i did check **subnet_boundary** variable and set the the value based on it

```
  subnet_id              = var.subnet_boundary == "public" ? var.ec2_public_subnets : var.ec2_private_subnets
```

And it works like charm

```
  + source_dest_check                    = true
  + subnet_id                            = "sn-pubxxxxxx"
  + tags                                 = {
      + "Name" = ""
    }
```